# global optimization algorithms in NLOPT

Tags: optimization, global, nlopt

I experience the problems with few global optimization algorithms implemented in NLopt software. In particular, ESCH (evolutionary algorithm) is not working properly in my case, the energy function is called large amount of iterations, the energy does not change. This is how my code calls the function

```
    void OPTIMIZESTRUCTURENLOPT (Conformer **conformer, 
    long int NBONDS, Fragment *fragments, 
    long int NATOMS, long int ITER, double TESTSIZE) {

    //  printf("Start of opt\n");
    long int i1, j, ii;
    nlopt_opt opt;
    opt = nlopt_create(NLOPT_GN_ESCH, NBONDS);
    nlopt_set_min_objective(opt, ENERGYNLOPT, (void *) (*conformer));
    nlopt_set_xtol_rel(opt, 1e-3);

    // the initial guess
    (**conformer).IT=0;
    double *x = malloc(NBONDS*sizeof(double)); //   [NBONDS];
    double *dx = malloc(NBONDS*sizeof(double)); //[NBONDS];
    double *lb = malloc(NBONDS*sizeof(double));
    double *ub = malloc(NBONDS*sizeof(double));
    for (i1=0;i1<NBONDS;i1++) {
        x[i1] = (**conformer).angles[i1];
        dx[i1] = 0.1;
        lb[i1] = -360;
        ub[i1] = 360;
    }
    nlopt_set_initial_step(opt, dx);
    nlopt_set_lower_bounds(opt, lb);
    nlopt_set_upper_bounds(opt, ub);
   //   printf ("Start: ");
    for (i1=0;i1<NBONDS;i1++) {
    //      printf ("%f ", x[i1]);
    }
    //  printf ("\n");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    nlopt_opt opt_loc;
    opt_loc = nlopt_create(NLOPT_LN_PRAXIS, NBONDS);
    nlopt_set_local_optimizer(opt, opt_loc);
    nlopt_set_xtol_rel(opt_loc, 1e-5);
    nlopt_set_ftol_rel(opt_loc, 1e-5);

    double minf; // the energy function value
    if (nlopt_optimize(opt, x, &minf) < 0) {
        printf ("nlopt failed!\n");
     }
    else {
        printf ("found minimum after (%li) iterations = %0.010g\n", 
     (**conformer).IT, minf);
        for (i1=0;i1<NBONDS;i1++) {
    //          printf ("%f ", x[i1]);
        }
    //      printf ("\n");
     }
```

And this is the energy function calls:

```
Iter: 10047  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10048  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10049  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10050  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10051  E = -1628.944283 
Iter: 10052  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10053  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10054  E = -1628.997908 
Iter: 10055  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10056  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10057  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10058  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10059  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10060  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10061  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10062  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10063  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10064  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10065  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10066  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10067  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10068  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10069  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10070  E = -1628.745543 
Iter: 10071  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10072  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10073  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10074  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10075  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10076  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10077  E = -1628.540874 
Iter: 10078  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10079  E = -1629.325853 
Iter: 10080  E = -1629.325853
```

Other algorithms works better - like ISRES (Improved Stochastic Ranking Evolution Strategy) and Controlled Random Search (CRS) with local mutation.

Any hints/ideas?